# Spring framework library

Tags: spring

Can I make a library with Spring framework, and then include that library in an application that uses the Spring framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can make a library that uses Spring, and then include a dependency on that jar in another application created with Spring. You will want a build tool that handles dependencies, like Maven or Gradle, and probably a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory to store artifacts that you create.

You have to make sure that the jar gets included in the component scan performed by the hosting application. See the Spring reference documentation on [Importing configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html).

If the library has its own Configuration, importing the Confuguration gets it included in the component scan.

Alternatively create a marker interface in your library like this:

```
@ComponentScan
public interface MyLibrary {}
```

then in the including application have a Configuration class annotated with

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= { MyLibrary.class })
```

and the including application will scan all Components in the package hierarchy starting from the package of the marker interface.

Comment: Do you have any example of that?

Answer (score 0):

Spring is open source so you can contribute to it. Refer to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md for more details.

Comment: Maybe I did not express my question well. I want to make a library using Spring framework, and then, include that library in an application that use Spring framework, too.

Comment: You can create a library using Spring framework and can include it in Spring Framework application as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any Java based applicaiton (like spring framework) can be packaged as a JAR file and published to a repository (or store it locally to start simple)

This Jar file can be included as a dependency in another Java based application (like spring framework)

To add dependencies you can either use Maven or place it in a directory and add it to local classpath for the next application to use the library.

Your library becomes a reusable library (usually a JAR file) for all other java based applications